# Is writing/reading speed affected by the name of the files?

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, utf-8

How can I find out, or does anybody know, if is faster storing/reading a file with Spanish/Greek/Cyrilic/etc... characters like `mi-foto-españa-oíóáaç.jpg` than `mi-foto-espana-oioaac.jpg` ?

Comment: Make a script that does it a million times and time it ? :)

Comment: Good point, I'll give a try later

Comment: Sure, benchmark it. But I would be very surprised if the name of the file made any difference at all. Why do you suspect it might?

Comment: @Celada I was just curious... latter I will benchmark the same thing but for apache, see if any difference there.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt very much that the name of the file will affect the read/write speed of the system to a file. The reason being that once the file is open all actions on it take place through the file descriptor ([fd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)) and the name is not used.

Comment: Furthermore, the filename is just a byte string on Linux. No conversion between character sets will occur